# NSCalendar to get date difference between now and end of year gives a zero month

Tags: ios, iphone-sdk-3.0, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I'm getting a 0 for the month when I try to get the date difference from now and the end of the year. I'm using a `NSCalendar` object to get the difference between two `NSDate` objects.

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setYear:2013];
[comps setMonth:0];
[comps setDay:0];

[comps setHour:0];
[comps setMinute:0];
[comps setSecond:0];

NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];

NSDateComponents *timeDifference = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] 
    components: NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | 
                NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit  
    fromDate:[NSDate date] toDate:newDate options:0];

int months = timeDifference.month;
int days = timeDifference.day;
if (months>0)
    days+=31;
int hours = timeDifference.hour;
int minutes = timeDifference.minute;
int seconds = timeDifference.second;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to calculate number of months, days, etc to year 2013. In `NSDateComponents` 0 means 'no value', all values that count should be greater than 0. That's why your `comps` value is considered as 'incomplete', which causes strange output from `NSCalendar`.

Set `month` and `day` in lines 3-4 to 1 fix the issue.